# Jquery stop play function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, playback

**How i can do it ?**

I have this code :

```
function Slide(i) 
{
    slide_1(id);

    $("#stop").click(function() 
    {
    event.stopPropagation();
    });

}
```

**I want stop function propagation and before i can create other function for play other time all process**

**Also i try this :**

```
var ac_activate_auto="si";

$("#play").click(function() { 
    /// load vars
    ac_activate_auto="si";
});


$("#stop").click(function() {
    /// load vars
    activate_auto="no";
});
```

This works but if i go and push over div id stop the animate stop but when i go and push over play no work other time

If you think there are other way ok , perfect , Regards and thank´s for all

Comment: Isn't this the same question you posted an hour or so ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759394/jquery-load-new-vars

Comment: Simlar question in one i want know hoe stop funtion and in other how insert vars with click function